# looking for "angular way" of closing open menu when page is clicked

Tags: angularjs

This is what I have, and it works (thankfully, angular supports jQuery out of the box if its loaded)....but I'm wondering what the "angular way" is to accomplish this.

I want to close the open menu if you click anywhere else on the page, but the menu:

```
<body ng-click="onClickPage($event)">


//app controller:

$scope.onClickPage = function(e){
    $log.log(e);
    $rootScope.$broadcast('click:page', e);
};

//navbar controller

$rootScope.$on('click:page', function(ev, e){
    var $el = $(e.target);

    if ( !$el.parents('.menu').length && !$el.hasClass('.menu') ) {
        $log.log('hide dropdown');
        $scope.hideDropdown();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That might depend on how your dropdown is implemented but a general idea is to bind/unbind click event handler to the $document when open/close the dropdown.

By doing this way,it doesn't polute global event listeners and $rootScope while the dropdown is not opened.

```
function onDocumentClicked(e) {
  var dropdownEl = angular.element('.dropdown');
  if (e && dropdownEl && dropdownEl[0].contains(e.target)) {
      return; // do nothing if clicked inside the dropdown
  }

  closeDropdown();
  $scope.$apply();
}

function openDropdown() {
  if (!$scope.dropdown.isOpen) {
    $scope.dropdown.isOpen = true;
    $document.bind('click', onDocumentClicked);
  }
}

function closeDropdown() {
  if ($scope.dropdown.isOpen) {
    $document.unbind('click', onDocumentClicked);
    $scope.dropdown.isOpen = false;
  }
}
```

**For the full example see:** http://plnkr.co/edit/mbx0sLnPetctlWNYdpJC?p=preview

Comment: also, is `$document` a global or do I need to inject it?

Comment: You need to inject the [$document](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$document). BTW, it is equivalent to `angular.element(window.document)`.